# How to send data from facebook-login-button?

Tags: php, html, database, facebook

I have a few questions all related.. I'll try to put them out in a logical fashion here.

First off, I'm using this button to have users connect to their Facebook from my webstie

```
<div class="fb-login-button" scope='email,publish_actions,user_likes'>
    Login with Facebook
</div>
```

It works. I can connect, and use some of the api calls like info.name, info.email etc to display this data on the site. Right now it's just a private test site.. obviously will be hiding this once it goes live.

What I would like to do, is essentially store the email addresses of users who connect. Preferably in a MySQL database on my server, or even just outputting to a text file... I did not see any way to get all this data from the app management page, or else I could just use that. Also did not see any way to get this data using FQL, if there is, please let me kow.

In terms of the MySQl database, I went ahead and made one on my server. Created a table, and I can insert data into it in this fashion:

```
<?php 
$link = mysql_connect('address', 'name', 'pass'); 
if (!$link) { 
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 
if ($link) {
    $myFile = "testFile.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    $stringData = "DATABASE YOOO";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    mysql_select_db(fb_test);   
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO demographic VALUES (123456, 'Fakey','Fakerson', 'fakey@noweb.com')");

    fclose($fh);
}
?>
```

I can go to myFile.txt and it shows "Database yo" also if I do a select query on the database, I can see the "Fakey Fakerson" etc. This would be a great route to go if I could figure out how to get the data I'm obtaining from the Facebook API into that. I'm calling that php file at the top of my HTML, in < head >

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="address/dbconnect.php"></script>
```

As far as I can find out.. been doing lots of searching (maybe the wrong queries) and I have no idea how to pass data from the page into that script. I was also looking into passing the data via POST, but couldn't quite figure it out. If there is a way to do this, either building off my (potentially wrong) way so far, or a totally new way.. I'd love to hear about it. Like I said, I've been Googling everywhere to try and find answers.. but just can't seem to get anything going.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass value from javascript to php using address bar](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10626549/how-to-pass-value-from-javascript-to-php-using-address-bar)

Comment: Thanks, that might be able to help, but I don't want to pass the data through the address bar. I'll just keep doing some research I guess.